# Why does IE "paint" function create lag when editing textarea?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, citrix

We're experiencing a fairly annoying lag in typing whenever our web application is used via Citrix VDI. The lag is most noticeable on a modal dialog where the user can edit a comment field. The dialog is standard bootstrap:

```
<div class="modal" id="id_ov_notes_editor" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="true" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="well">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <textarea id="id_ov_notes_editor_textarea" class="form-control" rows="25"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

We only see the lag in Internet Explorer (10 and 11), and only on Citrix.

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [umbrella.ch](https://www.umbrella.ch/simon/ui-responsiveness.png))</sub>

The top portion shows the IE "UI Responsiveness" summary for IE running on Citrix VDI. The bottom portion shows the same user interaction using a IE running on my local PC. Both times, the only action is to type text into the textarea. The purple part is attributed to the IE "Paint" function, taking up 17% time on the local PC, but 61% on Citrix VDI.

Why does "Paint" take up so much time on the Citrix VDI? Is there anything we can do in our web application to reduce this? Is there any VDI setting?

**EDIT:**
Further tests show that the lag is directly dependent on the display size of the textarea. With a simple HTML showing only a textarea, the lag is not noticeable with a rather small browser window, and increases dramatically when maximizing the window.

Thanks
Simon

Comment: And is there any events tied to the input?

Comment: a device's GPU normally accelerates such rendering (even in IE), but over the remote, the GPU probably doesn't get a chance to kick in anywhere along the rendering pipeline. a hardware KVM should show the same display perf as a physical desktop.

Comment: @epascarello, we do have listeners on keyup and keydown. That was the first thing I looked into, disabling those listeners completely didn't change typing performance at all.

Comment: One thing I just noticed is that the typing delay increases with a larger text area (large as in display size).